# Flutter Project Icon

Tags: flutter, dart

I made the icon for my app but still flutter logo is available and How can I solve the problem.

in pubspec.yaml:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgoHv.png)

> name: kidsgame
> description: A new Flutter project.
>
> ## The following line prevents the package from being accidentally
>
> published to
> # pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
> publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
>
> ```
> # The following defines the version and build number for your application.
> # A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
> # followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
> # Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
> # build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
> # In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
> # Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
> # In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
> # Read more about iOS versioning at
> # https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
> version: 1.0.0+1
>
> environment:
>   sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"
>
> # Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
> # To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
> # consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
> # dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
> # the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
> # versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
> dependencies:
>   flutter:
>     sdk: flutter
>
>
>   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
>   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
>   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
>   audioplayers:
>   flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
>
>
>
>
>
>
> dev_dependencies:
>   flutter_test:
>     sdk: flutter
>   flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"
>
> flutter_icons:
>   android: "launcher_icon"
>   ios: true
>   image_path: "assets/icons/logo.png"
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>   # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
>   # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
>   # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
>   # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
>   # rules and activating additional ones.
> flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
>
> # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
> # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
>
>
>
> # The following section is specific to Flutter.
> flutter:
>
>   # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
>   # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
>   # the material Icons class.
>   uses-material-design: true
>
>   # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
>   # assets:
>   assets:
>     - assets/clap.mp3
>   #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
>   #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
>
>   # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
>   # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
>
>   # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
>   # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
>
>   # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
>   # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
>   # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
>   # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
>   # example:
>   # fonts:
>   #   - family: Schyler
>   #     fonts:
>   #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
>   #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
>   #         style: italic
>   #   - family: Trajan Pro
>   #     fonts:
>   #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
>   #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
>   #         weight: 700
>   #
>   # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
>   # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
> ```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lPn6.pn
```

g

Comment: I wrote an article about this, you can read it [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-add-custom-icons-to-your-flutter-application-463dbd35fd39).

Comment: Also, did you run ```flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main``` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flutter launcher icon : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

It will help you manage your app icons.

Comment: That's what he did